# How to add variable in Google Map URL API Key string to be read from Conf file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Hi I have to read Google Map APIKey from Config file, and need to make a variable in the google map URL string instead of hard-coded APIKey but I'm unable to do so.

**This is the code I need to add variable in**

```
@{ var googleAPIKey = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["APIKey_GoogleMap_BaseUrl"]; 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

 }
```

***I tried the below but I'm still can't achieve it.***

```
@{ var googleAPIKey = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["APIKey_GoogleMap_BaseUrl"]; 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/" + googleAPIKey + ""></script>

 }
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
@{ var googleAPIKey = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["APIKey_GoogleMap_BaseUrl"]; 

    <script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/" + @googleAPIKey + ""></script>

 }
```

before this make sure you have added your google api key in your web.config file like below:

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="APIKey_GoogleMap_BaseUrl" value="google api key goes here" />
</appSettings>
```

hope it will helps you.

Thanks,